# Como expandir linha tabela com click

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Estou fazendo uma tabela e nela tera uma tr visivel e abaixo uma oculta e assim sucessivamente. 
Na tr visivel coloquei uma classe 'expandirTabela' e na oculta uma classe 'tabelaOculta'. Na hora do clique invés de abrir a correspondente acaba abrindo todas as ocultas de uma vez, no jquery fiz assim

```
var tabelaOculta =  $(".tabelaOculta").hide();
var oculta = false;
$(".expandirTabela").click(function(){

    if(oculta == false){
        $(this).parent().find(".tabelaOculta").show();
        oculta = true;

    }else{
        $(this).parent().find(".tabelaOculta").hide();
        oculta = false;
    }
});
```

e minha tabela

```
<tr class="expandirTabela">
    <td>+</td>
    <td>R$ 60.000,00</td>
    <td>R$ 15.000,00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tabelaOculta">
    <td colspan="3">
        <table>
            <tr>
                 <td>conteúdo oculto aqui</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Onde você está ocultando antes de chamar o evento onclick. Ao carregar a página? ou no CSS?

Comment: Amigo você pode usar o collapse do bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/, veja se é disso que você precisa.

Comment: isso após carregar a página

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver assim

```
var tabelaOculta =  $(".tabelaOculta").hide();
var oculta = false;

$(".expandirTabela").click(function(){

    if(oculta == false){
        $(this).parent().next('.tabelaOculta').show();
        oculta = true;

    }else if(oculta == true){
        tabelaOculta.hide();
        oculta = false;
    }
});
```